# Обработка переключения страниц в QWizard

Tags: qt

Есть ли способ отловить переключение на другую страницу для `QWizard`?

Comment: Всегда читайте официальную документацию перед тем, как задавать вопросы. Я ни разу не работал с Qt - просто открыл поисковик.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QWizard::currentIdChanged](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwizard.html#currentIdChanged)